# Iterating a loop++ without a script in google sheets?

Tags: loops, google-sheets

```
A1: 10
A2: 5
```

Is it possible to loop through this in google sheets combining count and array formula or will I need to write a ++ script?

I would like the output to be:

```
B1: 10
B2: 9
B3: 8
B4: 7
B5: 6
B6: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=sequence(A2+1,1,A1,-1)
```